# Extra whitespace in FAQ navigation tooltips

Tags: bug, status-completed, site-faq, whitespace

Some of the tooltips on the navigation menu on the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) page have leading whitespace in them. Also, some of the items don't have tooltips at all.

This is visible both in Chrome 15 and Firefox 6 on Ubuntu 11.04.

[image: too much leading whitespace]

[image: same thing here]

It is also visible with Safari 5.1 on Mac OS X.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Spinning up an Ubuntu VM and taking a look, looks like the trim behavior is different there for some strange reason.

Comment: I see the same on Safari 5.1, and Mac OS X 10.7. It doesn't happen with all the links, but with the ones shown in the screenshot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok for some reason my local Chrome install doesn't repro this, but Safari does.

In any case, it's just a simple `$.trim()` call to resolve it, so this will look correct in all browsers next build.